# Convert Array of Objects to Key Value Structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This might be a very basic JS question.

I just want to figure out if there can be any alternative solutions of the same logic.

```
var testArray =[{Name:"Defg",Age:"17",Level:"four"},
        {Name:"Abcd",Age:"12",Level:"four"},
        {Name:"Hijk",Age:"11",Level:"two"},     
        {Name:"Pqrs",Age:"21",Level:"three"},
        {Name:"Vwxy",Age:"15",Level:"three"}];
getLevelMap: function (testArray) {
    var levelMap = [];
    var that = this;
    testArray.forEach(function (item) {
     if (!levelMap.includes(item.Level)) {
          levelMap.push(item.Level);
          var generalDetails = [item];
          levelMap[item.Level] = generalDetails;
         } else {
          var existingLevel = levelMap[item.Level];
          existingLevel = existingLevel.push(item);
          };
    });
    levelMap.sort();
    return levelMap;
}
```

Calling getLevelMap(testArray) should give me the following result:

```
(3) ["four", "three", "two", four: Array(2), two: Array(1), three: Array(2)]
0: "four"
1: "three"
2: "two"

four: Array(2)
0: {Name: "Defg", Age: "17", Level: "four"}
1: {Name: "Abcd", Age: "12", Level: "four"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

three: Array(2)
0: {Name: "Pqrs", Age: "21", Level: "three"}
1: {Name: "Vwxy", Age: "15", Level: "three"}
length: 2

__proto__: Array(0)
two: Array(1)
0: {Name: "Hijk", Age: "11", Level: "two"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code by using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var testArray =[{Name:"Defg",Age:"17",Level:"four"},
        {Name:"Abcd",Age:"12",Level:"four"},
        {Name:"Hijk",Age:"11",Level:"two"},     
        {Name:"Pqrs",Age:"21",Level:"three"},
        {Name:"Vwxy",Age:"15",Level:"three"}];

var result = testArray.reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.Level] = (c[v.Level] || []).concat([v]);
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```